# Is there any way to fire a touch event with an Android accessibility service?

Tags: android, service, accessibility

I have an accessibility service that is able to click on resources in another app, however some resources do not accept click events and are expecting touch events.

Is there any way to make an accessibility service fire a touch event on a resource instead of a click event?

Comment: Accessibility services in N can dispatch touch gestures, but the documentation isn't online yet. Look at AccessibilityService.dispatchGesture() in the N SDK's documentation.

Comment: Very interesting. Is that the only documentation you know of or do you know of any examples? I am trying to work it out, but dispatchGesture() is returning false for me every time.